# Android Retrofit2 generics method

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, retrofit2

## I use Retrofit2 to connect to the server,

To simplify the number of request methods, I use generics. But the problem is that retrofit does not accept the generic method. I put the sample code below. Does anyone know a solution?

#### Photo 1):

[APIInterface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRR8a.png)

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.POST
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface APIInterface {

   @POST("{url}") fun <T> post(
      @Path("url") url: String,
      @Body body: RequestBody
   ): Observable<T>

   @GET("{url}") fun <T> get(
      @Path("url") url: String
   ): Observable<T>
}
```

#### Photo 2:

[APIService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0iZR.png)

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import java.io.Serializable

class APIService constructor(private val mApi: APIInterface) {

   fun <T: Serializable> post(url: String, body: RequestBody): Observable<T>{
      val observable = mApi.post<T>(url, body)
      observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      return observable
   }

   fun <T: Serializable> get(url: String): Observable<T> {
      val observable = mApi.get<T>(url)
      observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      return observable
   }
}
```

#### Photo 3:

[call in controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFOTr.png)

```
mAPIService.post<SignUpModel>(URL_SIGN_UP, body)
        .subscribe(object : APIObserver<SignUpModel> {
            override fun onNext(it: SignUpModel) {
    .
    .
    .
```

#### Photo 4:

[crash :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IOjM.png)

```
W: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method return type must not include a type variable or wildcard: io.reactivex.Observable<T>
W: for method APIInterface.post
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Add your code as text.not screenshots

Comment: Please don't post image. insted add a code for better understanding

Comment: you can see again. @DilanAnuruddha

Comment: you can see again. @Parth

Comment: You could probably use `Observable<Any>`

Comment: No. Problems with "fun <T> post": T Generic Type. @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type information needs to be fully known at runtime in order for
>   deserialization to work.

You cannot do this,the type info needs to be fully static and not a generic, otherwise retrofit cannot correctly generate the Service. Look at [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2012).

Answer (score -1):

Just adding some common class and by this code snippet you can easily call any api

```
 val repository = Repository(UseCase<YourModel>())

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            RetrofitClient.apiEndpoint?.getXyz(
                YourModel(value)
            )?.let {
                repository.fetchData(
                    it
                ) { yourModel, error ->
                    if (error != null) {
                        // Handle error
                        Log.d("CheckingResponse", "$error")
                    } else {
                        // ..success
                    }
                  }
                }
        }
```

Client

```
object RetrofitClient {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://xyz/"
    private var client = OkHttpClient.Builder() // add our curl logger here
        .addInterceptor(CurlLoggerInterceptor()) // curl logger to get curl when any api hits (You need to add dependency to use this)
    private val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client.build())
        .build()

    val apiEndpoint: ApiEndpoint? = retrofit.create(ApiEndpoint::class.java)

}
```

usecase

```
class UseCase<T> {
    fun fetchData(endpoint: Call<ApiResponse<T>>, callback: (T?, String?) -> Unit) {
        endpoint.enqueue(object : Callback<ApiResponse<T>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ApiResponse<T>>, response: Response<ApiResponse<T>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseData = response.body()?.data
                    callback(responseData, null)
                } else {
                    Log.d("CheckingResponse", "fetchData: ${response.message()}")
                    callback(null, "Error: ${response.message()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse<T>>, t: Throwable) {
                callback(null, "Network error: ${t.localizedMessage}")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

check out this for all common class.
https://github.com/Mohammad-Taqi/Generic-Retrofit-Implementation

Comment: Mohammad Taqi, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Done! :) 
Is it okay now?

Comment: I Updated my answer with details and relevent code.